# Validating date format with Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if the format of the date input by user matches the below:

```
Jan 5 2018 6:10 PM

Month: First letter should be caps, followed 2 more in small. (total 3 letters)
<Space>: single space, must exist
Date: For single digit it should not be 05, but 5
<Space>: single space, must exist
Hour: 0-12, for single digit it should not be 06, but 6
Minute: 00-59
AM/PM
```

I'm using the below regex and trying to match:

```
import re,sys
usr_date = str(input("Please enter the older date until which you want to scan ? \n[Date Format Example: Jan 5 2018 6:10 PM] :  "))

valid_usr_date = re.search("^(\s+)*[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}\s{1}[1-31]{1}\s{1}[1-2]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}\s{1}[0-12]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}\s{1}(A|P)M$",usr_date,re.M)

if not valid_usr_date:
    print ("The date format is incorrect. Please follow the exact date format as shown in example. Exiting Program!")
    sys.exit()
```

But, even  for the correct format it gives a `syntax wrong` error. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: `[1-31]` matches `1`, `2` or `3`. Character classes do not work as you think they do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you have the right answer, but you entered it as a "comment". Write it as an "answer" instead, and the questioner can give you credit for your answer!

Comment: Can I ask why use this format and not something that can be easily parsed by `datetime.strptime`?

Comment: @ReutSharabani This code above is part of a bigger code with a lot of functions defined. I already have certain functions where I'm parsing different parts of the date with `datetime.strptime`, but that is well ahead in my program. Before even going there I want to keep a validate function where I validate all inputs from user, and if doesn't validate, the program exits and doesn't go any further. Moreover I don't want to bind my program modules with multiple `try: except:`. I, rather am using `sys.excepthook` which captures all exceptions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not use regex for that, as you have no way to actually validate the date itself (eg, a regex will happily accept `Abc 99 9876 9:99 PM`).

Instead, use `strptime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

string = 'Jan 5 2018 6:10 PM'
datetime.strptime(string, '%b %d %Y %I:%M %p')
```

If the string would be in the "wrong" format you'd get a `ValueError`.

The only apparent "problem" with this approach is that for some reason you require the day and hour not to be zero-padded and `strptime` doesn't seem to have such directives.

A table with all available directives is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function which parses the input string and tries to return a `datetime` object, if it can't it raises an `ValueError`:

```
from datetime import datetime

def valid_date(s):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    except ValueError:
        msg = "Not a valid date: '{0}'.".format(s)
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
```

Comment: This code I mentioned above in my query, is part of a bigger code with a lot of functions defined. I already have certain functions where I'm parsing different parts of the date with `datetime.strptime`, but that is well ahead in my program. Before even going there I want to keep a validate function where I validate all inputs from user, and if doesn't validate, the program exits and doesn't go any further. Moreover I don't want to bind my program modules with multiple try: except:. I, rather am using `sys.excepthook` which captures all exceptions